How to tell Windows Explorer to properly and completely refresh its icons using Powershell?
I do a lot of icon design. When I modify a windows Icon and overwrite the original, explorer doesn't refresh and show the new icon.
If I change the name of the new icon so it's unique, the change I made shows up correctly. However if it's the same name as the original unmodified icon, it still shows the old icon. It seems like Win10 is caching the icon by name.
How can I force windows 10's explorer.exe to refresh it's icon cache using Pwsh?
I found this post about the same thing, but the code is in C, which I don't understand or have any proficiency with:
How to tell Windows Explorer to refresh its icons?
Is there any easy way to call SHChangeNotify SHUpdateImage or WM_SETTINGCHANGE from within Powershell?
Is there a C# assembly I can use that defines a helper class to notify Windows that it needs to refresh its cache?
What I've tried sofar:
function Request-WindowsExplorerRefresh {
    param (
        [switch] $SendF5,
        [Int32] $SendF5Delay=150
    )

    $shellApplication = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
    $windows = $shellApplication.Windows()
    $count = $windows.Count()

    foreach( $i in 0..($count-1) ) {
        $item = $windows.Item( $i )
        if( $item.Name() -like '*Explorer*' ) {
            $item.Refresh()
        }
    }

    if($SendF5){
        $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $SendF5Delay
        $wshell.SendKeys("{F5}")
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $SendF5Delay
        $wshell.SendKeys("{F5}")
    }
}

The above code using Com with Shell.Application to tell explorer to refresh. And I have an optional switch to additionally press F5 a couple times to refresh the window. Unfortunately this function isn't working and doesn't actually refresh the icon cache.
I also have tried this approach, utilizing a C# helper class:
function Request-WindowsExplorerRefreshAlt {
    param ()

$code = @"
using System;
namespace VSYS
{
    public static class Util
    {

        public static void RefreshExplorer(){

            Console.WriteLine("Refreshing Explorer");

            Guid CLSID_ShellApplication = new Guid("13709620-C279-11CE-A49E-444553540000");
            Type shellApplicationType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_ShellApplication, true);

            object shellApplication = Activator.CreateInstance(shellApplicationType);
            object windows = shellApplicationType.InvokeMember("Windows", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, shellApplication, new object[] { });

            Type windowsType = windows.GetType();
            object count = windowsType.InvokeMember("Count", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, windows, null);
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)count; i++)
            {
                object item = windowsType.InvokeMember("Item", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, windows, new object[] { i });
                if (item != null) {
                    Type itemType = item.GetType();
                    // only refresh windows explorer
                    string itemName = (string)itemType.InvokeMember("Name", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, item, null);
                    if ((itemName == "Windows Explorer") || (itemName == "File Explorer")) {
                        itemType.InvokeMember("Refresh", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, item, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
"@
    Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp
    Invoke-Expression "[VSYS.Util]::RefreshExplorer()"
}

This code doesn't work either. So I'm kind of spinning my wheels right now and can't find any kind of solution. I think the key has something to do with calling SHChangeNotify SHUpdateImage or broadcasting WM_SETTINGCHANGE. But I have absolutely no clue how to do this in Powershell (or C#)
I could really use some help with this as the current windows behavior is driving me up the wall.
Any help greatly appreciated.

If you can swap the icon name in powershell, that might be easier. Just copy it to %TEMP%\icon_%TIMESTAMP%.ico or something.

I need the individual icon names to be consistent. If I edit an icon and save it, I want the change to appear even if it has the same name as the icon it overwrote. What I'm looking for is a way to invalidate the icon cache so I can just call a single command to refresh all icons correctly.

Sure, that's what you want. But if you can't do that easily enough, then writing a script to rename the icon would be a reasonable workaround. For development purposes at least.

https://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHChangeNotify.html

@Luke That helps a lot, thank you. Though I'm not clear on how to implement that in Powershell. I guess I need to write the class in C# and then Add-Type it to my function? Not sure how to structure the class.

Pretty much yeah, you need C# and Add-Type to do PInvoke, but it works fine. What PInvoke call do you actually want to make, you name three functions but not how you want to use them?


To let Windows Explorer know something has changed you need to force a refresh.
In your case, you may try simply restarting the explorer process:
Stop-Process -ProcessName explorer

Another approach could be using Win32 APIs like this:
function Refresh-Explorer {
    $code = @'
private static readonly IntPtr HWND_BROADCAST = new IntPtr(0xffff);   //  http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/HWND.html
private const uint WM_SETTINGCHANGE   = (uint)0x1a;                   //  http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/WM.html
private const uint SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG   = (uint)0x0002;                 //  http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/SendMessageTimeoutFlags.html
private const uint SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED = (uint)0x08000000L;            //  http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/SHChangeNotifyEventID.html
private const uint SHCNF_FLUSH        = (uint)0x1000;                 //  http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/SHChangeNotifyFlags.html

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout (IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, string lParam, uint fuFlags, uint uTimeout, IntPtr lpdwResult);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
private static extern int SHChangeNotify(uint eventId, uint flags, IntPtr item1, IntPtr item2);

public static void Refresh()  {
    SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_FLUSH, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, null, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 100, IntPtr.Zero);
}
'@

    Add-Type -MemberDefinition $code -Namespace Win32Refresh -Name Explorer
    [Win32Refresh.Explorer]::Refresh()
}

# call the above function to tell explorer something has changed
Refresh-Explorer

